# Employee shift roster in python

Tags: python, shift

I am scripting a shift roster for my team. consider, there are 'a' number of Seniors (few in one location and few in another), 'b' number of Team leads(few in one location and few in another), 'c' number of Duty Managers(few in one location and few in another). I want to create a shift roster in python for them.

Conditions are as follows.

1. date range will be for an year 01-Jan-2002 to 31-Dec-2020.
2. There will be 3 shifts, I need to accommodate a+b+c resources in 3 shifts (~ equally)
3. each shift should have 1 primary and 1 secondary resource.
4. Since it is a weekly shift, resources should get shuffled. lets say if a1 is primary and a2 is secondary during shift 1 week 1, a2 should be primary and a1 should be secondary during shift 2 week 2 and so on. (This part I feel is difficult) Appreciate any help in this.

How is it possible while iterating through each day, to pick resources for each shift, primary and secondary?

typical roster should look like this.

[typical roster should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhrFH.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Here is how I implemented it. Please see below codes with explanation.

Import statements

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import random
```

Input start date and end date for which period roster to be prepared

```py
start_date = dt.date(2020,6,1)
end_date = dt.date(2020,12,31)
```

Create a DataFrame

```py
roster=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date',
                            'Week Number',
                             'Day',
                           'INDIA SHIFT 1 PRIMARY',
                           'INDIA SHIFT 1 Secondary',
                           'INDIA SHIFT 2 PRIMARY',
                           'INDIA SHIFT 2 Secondary',
                           'US SHIFT PRIMARY',
                           'US SHIFT SECONDARY',
                           'Weekend On-call Primary',
                           'Weekend On-call Secondary',
                           'Duty Manager 1',
                           'Duty Manager 2',
                           'Duty Manager Weekend'])
```

Filled the DF with Date, Week number, Weekday

```py
required_date = []
week_no = []
weekday = []

daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
for single_date in daterange:
    required_date.append(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    week_no.append(single_date.isocalendar()[1])
    weekday.append(single_date.strftime("%A"))

roster['Date'] = required_date
roster['Week Number'] = week_no
roster['Day'] = weekday
```

My current DF looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVlog.png)

Then I am reading the input file containing Resources and holidays

```py
Resources = pd.read_excel('Input_Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Resources')
Holidays = pd.read_excel('Input_Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Holidays')
```

Resources and Holidays DF looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X4K3.png)

Then I am optimizing the holidays and removing null values

```py
Holidays.India = Holidays.India.astype(str)
Holidays.US = Holidays.US.astype(str)
Holidays.US = Holidays.US.apply(lambda x : None if x=='NaT' else x)
US_holidays = list(filter(None,list(Holidays.US)))
IND_holidays = list(Holidays.India)
```

Then I segregate regions wise holidays and common holidays

```py
# segregate holidays whether common holiday or region wise
def Optimize_IND_Holidays(IND_holidays):
    for i in IND_holidays:
        if(i < roster['Date'][0]):
            IND_holidays.remove(i)
            return Optimize_IND_Holidays(IND_holidays)
Optimize_IND_Holidays(IND_holidays)

def Optimize_US_Holidays(US_holidays):
    for i in US_holidays:
        if(i < roster['Date'][0]):
            US_holidays.remove(i)
            return Optimize_US_Holidays(US_holidays)
Optimize_US_Holidays(US_holidays)

common_holidays = []
for i in IND_holidays:
    for j in US_holidays:
        if i == j:
            common_holidays.append(i)
            IND_holidays.remove(i)
            US_holidays.remove(i)

common_holidays,IND_holidays , US_holidays
```

Segregating resources based on location because, when there is holiday in one location, other location resources should be in shift.

```py
IND_Res = list(Resources.IND) + list(Resources.TL)
US_Res = list(Resources.US)
US_Res, IND_Res
```

Now this is where I got stuck, though this is an interim solution, it is not ideal and does not work in real time. What I did here is, since there are only 2 resources per shift, for even and odd weeks, I alternatively assigned 1 TL, 1 Senior per shift. Duty managers are common for every week unless there is a holiday or weekend. I explicitly assigned here. So what I need a code/idea how I can implement this implicitly with python rather than manually assigning and also keeping the condition number 4 in mind.

```py
# get week numbers as list
weekno = list(roster['Week Number'])
shift1 = {}
shift2 = {}
shift3 = {}
# make a set from the week numbers list and sort them to iterate
for i in sorted(list(set(weekno))):
    if(int(i)%2==0):
        shift1.update({i:[Resources.TL[0],Resources.IND[0]]})
        shift2.update({i:[Resources.TL[1],Resources.IND[1]]})
        shift3.update({i:[Resources.US[0],Resources.US[1]]})
    else:
        shift1.update({i:[Resources.TL[1],Resources.IND[1]]})
        shift2.update({i:[Resources.TL[0],Resources.IND[0]]})
        shift3.update({i:[Resources.US[1],Resources.US[0]]})
```

Made a list for weekend staff

```py
weekend_Resources = list(Resources.IND)+list(Resources.US)
weekend_Managers = list(Resources.DutyManager)+list(Resources.TL)
weekend_combinations = [[a, b] for a in weekend_Resources  
          for b in weekend_Managers if a != b]
```

Here I am assigning resources for Weekdays and Weekends but not holidays.

```py
IND_shift1_prim = []
IND_shift1_sec = []
IND_shift2_prim = []
IND_shift2_sec = []
US_shift_prim = []
US_shift_sec = []
Duty1 = []
Duty2 = []
Weekend_prim = []
Weekend_sec = []
for j in sorted(list(set(weekno))):
    r1 = random.randint(0,len(weekend_combinations)-1)
    for i in range(len(roster)):
        if((roster['Week Number'][i]==j) and ((roster['Day'][i] != 'Saturday') and (roster['Day'][i] != 'Sunday'))):
            #print(roster['Date'][i],roster['Week Number'][i])
            IND_shift1_prim.append(shift1[j][0])
            IND_shift1_sec.append(shift1[j][1])
            IND_shift2_prim.append(shift2[j][0])
            IND_shift2_sec.append(shift2[j][1])
            US_shift_prim.append(shift3[j][0])
            US_shift_sec.append(shift3[j][1])
            Duty1.append(Resources.DutyManager[0])
            Duty2.append(Resources.DutyManager[1])
            Weekend_prim.append("")
            Weekend_sec.append("")
        if((roster['Week Number'][i]==j) and ((roster['Day'][i] == 'Saturday') or (roster['Day'][i] == 'Sunday'))):
            IND_shift1_prim.append("")
            IND_shift1_sec.append("")
            IND_shift2_prim.append("")
            IND_shift2_sec.append("")
            US_shift_prim.append("")
            US_shift_sec.append("")
            Duty1.append("")
            Duty2.append("")
            Weekend_prim.append(weekend_combinations[r1][0])
            Weekend_sec.append(weekend_combinations[r1][1])
```

For holidays resource assignment, below is the code.

```py
# for IND, US common holidays


for i in range(len(roster)):
    which_day = datetime.strptime((roster['Date'][i]),"%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%A')
    if (which_day != 'Saturday' and which_day != 'Sunday'):
        for j in range(len(common_holidays)):
            if(roster['Date'][i] == common_holidays[j]):
                r1 = random.randint(0,len(US_Res)-1)
                r2 = random.randint(0,len(IND_Res)-1)
                IND_shift1_prim[i] = IND_Res[r2]
                IND_shift1_sec[i] = US_Res[r1]
                IND_shift2_prim[i] = IND_Res[r2]
                IND_shift2_sec[i] = US_Res[r1]
                US_shift_prim[i] = US_Res[r1]
                US_shift_sec[i] = IND_Res[r2]
        # for India holidays
        for i in range(len(roster)):
            for j in range(len(IND_holidays)):
                if(roster['Date'][i] == IND_holidays[j]):
                    r1 = random.sample(range(0,len(US_Res)),2)
                    IND_shift1_prim[i] = US_Res[r1[0]]
                    IND_shift1_sec[i] = US_Res[r1[1]]
                    IND_shift2_prim[i] = US_Res[r1[1]]
                    IND_shift2_sec[i] = US_Res[r1[0]]
                    US_shift_prim[i] = US_Res[r1[0]]
                    US_shift_sec[i] = US_Res[r1[1]]
                    Duty1[i] = Resources.DutyManager[0]
                    Duty2[i] = Resources.DutyManager[0]

        #for US holidays
        for i in range(len(roster)):
            for j in range(len(US_holidays)):
                if(roster['Date'][i] == US_holidays[j]):
                    r1 = random.sample(range(0,len(IND_Res)),2)
                    IND_shift1_prim[i] = IND_Res[r1[0]]
                    IND_shift1_sec[i] = IND_Res[r1[1]]
                    IND_shift2_prim[i] = IND_Res[r1[1]]
                    IND_shift2_sec[i] = IND_Res[r1[0]]
                    US_shift_prim[i] = IND_Res[r1[0]]
                    US_shift_sec[i] = IND_Res[r1[1]]
                    Duty1[i] = Resources.DutyManager[1]
                    Duty2[i] = Resources.DutyManager[1]
```

Then I checked the length of each list against the length of the DataFrame itself to make sure they all are equal.

```py
# make sure length of each list is same as number of total days for which roster is being prepared
len(IND_shift1_prim),len(IND_shift1_sec),len(IND_shift2_prim),len(IND_shift2_sec),len(US_shift_prim),len(US_shift_sec),len(Duty1),len(Duty2),len(roster)
```

Then I assigned the lists to the columns of my dataframe.

```py
roster['INDIA SHIFT 1 PRIMARY'] = IND_shift1_prim
roster['INDIA SHIFT 1 Secondary'] = IND_shift1_sec
roster['INDIA SHIFT 2 PRIMARY'] = IND_shift2_prim
roster['INDIA SHIFT 2 Secondary'] = IND_shift2_sec
roster['US SHIFT PRIMARY'] = US_shift_prim
roster['US SHIFT SECONDARY'] = US_shift_sec
roster['Duty Manager 1'] = Duty1
roster['Duty Manager 2'] = Duty2
roster['Weekend On-call Primary'] = Weekend_prim
roster['Weekend On-call Secondary'] = Weekend_sec
```

Finally exported the dataframe to excel.

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('roster.xlsx') as writer:
    June_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'June')
    July_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'July')
    August_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'August')
    Sep_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'September')
    Oct_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'October')
    Nov_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'November')
    Dec_roster.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'December')
```

Final Dataframe looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGNlF.png)

This is what I did so far. Would anyone please advice how to code keeipng the condition 4 in mind?

Comment: Open-ended questions that detail a problem that happens to be solvable as a coding problem are generally off-topic on this site without showing how you attempted to solve the problem, and asking a *specific* question related to programming about a point at which you got stuck trying to solve the problem.  As it is, there are many possible answers to your question that would first have to presuppose a specific approach to solving the problem in general.  In other words, please show an attempt to write your own code.

Comment: @Iguananaut, thank you for your kind information. Appreciate it. I will edit the question again.

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better now.  Did you ever solve the problem?  Otherwise, I can take a look at it.

Comment: I was able to for the weekdays. But I need it make it better for weekends and holidays.